# UPSERT list of dictionaries in Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm attempting to insert into the table and if it exists (which I think is determined by just the primary key which is prod_id in this case), I want it to just overwrite the row.

Below is my incomplete attempt. DO UPDATE SET seems to be what I need but not sure how to use it here.

```
items = [
        {'prod_id': 'a2226', 'name': "TV", 'price': 5555},
        {'prod_id': 'b5221', 'name': "Speakers", 'price': 2522},
]
cols = items[0].keys()
cols_no_primary_key = items[0].keys().remove("prod_id")
query = "INSERT INTO items ({}) VALUES %s ON CONFLICT (prod_id) DO UPDATE SET ({}) = EXCLUDED. ".format(','.join(cols), ','.join(cols_no_primary_key))
vals = [[value for value in item.values()] for item in items]
execute_values(cursor, query, vals)
```

Comment: I don't think you can do that without mentioning column names. you have to mention column names one by one in update statement , not only in `upsert` but also in `update` statements  is like that.

Comment: You need to spend some more time here [SQL Composition](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/sql.html). For starters you left out `sql.SQL("INSERT ...).format()`